# Realtime alerts for page speed

Tags: performance, monitoring, alert, frontend, pagespeed

I'm looking for a tool that will send me an alert for page load time.

Think of a downtime alert, eg: Pingdom, but one that sends alerts once a page load time increases above a certain threshold. Eg: Alert that X page has taken greater than 7 seconds consistently for 30 minutes.

I know of a lot of tools that give you historical records and page speed metrics after the fact, or give you Apdex scores, but nothing that alerts around speed thresholds.

Does anyone know of such a tool?

Comment: Searching for tools is off-topic... Here is one http://www.keynote.com/

Answer (score 0):

Almost all website monitoring services have alerts when the response time is above certain threshold. Your question however is bit more specific since you have a time frame (30 min). Depending on the service used and the monitoring frequency, during a 30 min period you might have between 1 and 30 tests. Do you want an alert if all of those tests are above 7 seconds or if the average response time is above 7 seconds?

I can speak of [WebSitePulse](http://www.websitepulse.com/) where you can receive an alert if 1 or more tests in a row have detected a problem or if the page-load time is within certain limits.

Comment: I was thinking more so, if the 7 seconds was consistent, so average could be applicable.

Answer (score 0):

[GTmetrix.com](http://gtmetrix.com) Offers Daily alerts for Yslow and PageSpeed scores, as well as great breakdowns and grades for specific ticket items. Great freemium business model as well, free for 3 sites.

Upgraded versions include loading videos of your site.

Source: Just used it for my company's site.